# bootstrap navbar automatically collapses

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, asset-pipeline, navbar

I've deployed a mobile app that I've built on to Heroku, and a particular bootstrap UI element is not working as expected.

When I click to open the top nav bar on a smaller browser window (for example, on a mobile app), the menu expands and then automatically closes after a split second.  This isn't happening in development - only when I deploy to Heroku.

The URL for the app (easily reproducible):

http://statsly-staging.herokuapp.com

resize your browser window to a lower width.  Then click on the menu expansion icon on the right - this should open up a list of items.  However, it opens for a second and then automatically closes.   Completely baffling.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: solution: config.assets.debug was set to true in the env file that i used for heroku deployment, so all files ended up getting included twice - first for the individual line items, and the second time for the minified application.js file (which includes all scripts).  the solution was to set config.assets.debug to false, and that solved it

Answer (score 1):

@jli,

It seams confliction of js in your nav-bar. Remove all js except 'bootstrap.js'
 And Try.

Comment: awesome, that helped me solve it (the actual problem was somewhat related - more details in the original question) - thanks @vibz.

Comment: i don't understand so what should i do here i also have the same problem